# How to convert an "initWithBytes" NSString to unsigned char*

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, char

How to convert an "initWithBytes" NSString to unsigned char*?

here's how the NSString produced

```
NSString *byte = [[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:inputbytes length:inputlength encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
```

which contains bytes data that should not be changed in bit level(will be the input of base64 conversion)

The data in the byte is 0x01 0x00 0x01, 3 bytes

and I want to convert it into an unsigned char*

How should I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, you should work with `NSString` directly rather than attempting to move in and out of Objective-C. But there are reasons to drop down to C (e.g. using a C-only API) so I'll humour you. ;)

If you just need to pass the data to another function, you can do this:

```
const unsigned char *cString = (const unsigned char *)[byte cStringUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

If you need to modify the C string (i.e. make it non-`const`), you will need to make a copy:

```
const unsigned char *cString = (const unsigned char *)strdup([byte cStringUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
```

And then `free()` it when you're done with it:

```
free(cString);
```

Note that this will not modify the original C string or the `NSString` you made from it. If you need an `NSString` you can modify, use `NSMutableString`.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I did "have" to convert them into C string, since I'm using C libraries, and I'm familiar with C. I tried both methods, but the string I get seems to be empty, and the return value of strlen is 1. I'm wondering if there's something to do with "initWithBytes:inputbytes"? Thank you

Comment: The string you're working with is probably not pure ASCII. Does UTF-8 encoding work?

Comment: I found that the string is successfully copied(by accessing string[]), but the strlen function can't return the correct value. Thank you!

Comment: That implies a null character (`\0`) made it into the C string. What is the string you're testing with?

Comment: It's an output from the smartcard(doing RSA encyption).

Comment: Is it the decrypted output or encrypted output? And if it's binary data, you should be using `NSData`, not `NSString`, which can modify its characters when encodings are used.

Answer (score 0):

Try the cStringUsingEncoding: method of NSString:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-BAJHJHHD